# Android Chronometer has .start() and .stop() but not .get/setBase()

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, mono

Installed xamarin for VS15 Community

Class is using Android.Widget

Chronometer is in Android.Widget.Chronometer

At lines 6 and 11, I get "does not contain definition for method" error:

'Chronometer' does not contain a definition for 'setBase' and no extension method 'setBase' accepting a first argument of type 'Chronometer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But Chronometer DOES have definition for .Start() and .Stop(). Why no get/setBase?

HOWEVER

[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html#start()) notes that the methods should be lowercase: .start() and .stop()

I'm not sure where to start looking for reference/using problems?

```
        Chronometer chrono = FindViewById<Chronometer>(Resource.Id.chronometer1);
        var chronoActionButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnStopwatchController);
        chronoActionButton.Text = (!isRunning) ? Resources.GetString(Resource.String.stopwatchconrollerButton_text, "Start") : Resources.GetString(Resource.String.stopwatchconrollerButton_text, "Stop");
        chronoActionButton.Click += (object sender, System.EventArgs e) => {
            if (!isRunning) {
                chrono.setBase(SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + timeWhenStopped);
                isRunning = true;
                chronoActionButton.Text = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.stopwatchconrollerButton_text, "Stop");
                chrono.Start();
            } else {
                timeWhenStopped = chrono.getBase() - SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime();
                isRunning = false;
                chronoActionButton.Text = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.stopwatchconrollerButton_text, "Start");
                chrono.Stop();
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin generally translates methods and property names to more standard C# conventions - mixed case instead of lower, and using Property names instead of get/set methods.

So getBase and setBase are translated as just a single Base property with a getter and setter.

see: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.Chronometer/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! 1 question:
How will I know when to refer to Android's documentation or Xamarin's documentation?

Comment: For the most part you can refer to either documentation as long as you keep in mind what the C# equivalent will be. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/xamarin-for-java/#properties has more details on other language differences as well.

Answer (score 1):

Chronometer has a Base property. So instead of `chrono.GetBase()` you simply type `chrono.Base`